# Forcing edges on one side of a graph in DOT

Tags: graphviz, dot

In the following graph in DOT

```
graph {
rankdir=LR;
ranksep="1.0";
    "v_1086" [label="A"];
    "v_1023" [label="B"];
    "v_1181" [label="C"];
    "q_-888017763" [label="Q"];
    "c_-961691100" [label="1"];
    "c_-1161934348" [label="2"];
    "c_556655049" [label="3"];
    "v_1023"--"c_-961691100"[label="1.0"];
    "v_1086"--"c_-1161934348"[label="1.0"];
    "v_1181"--"c_556655049"[label="0.9925742574257426"];
    "q_-888017763"--"v_1086" [color="green"];
    "q_-888017763"--"v_1181" [color="indigo"];
    "q_-888017763"--"v_1023" [color="khaki4"];
    "c_-1161934348"--"c_-961691100"[label="1.0"];
    "c_556655049"--"c_-1161934348"[label="0.10282888897110791"];
    "c_556655049"--"c_-961691100"[label="0.006661529339994344"];
    {rank = same;
        "v_1086";
        "v_1023";
        "v_1181";
    };
    {rank = same;
        "q_-888017763";
    };
    {rank = same;
    };
    {rank = same;
        "c_-961691100";
        "c_-1161934348";
        "c_556655049";
    };
}
```

How can I move the edges between the numerical nodes to the left.

Answer (score 0):

The dot in the question renders as:

[image: graph]

In that context, I don't understand the question: The numerical nodes are on the right, not the left, and I don't understand why you'd want to move the edges between them. Move them where?

Sorry this isn't an answer, but I can't embed an image in a comment.